# How can i set MQMD message context in client WebsphereMQ?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Where should I set  MQMD message context in client WebsphereMQ?

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
mqConnectionFactory.setHostName(producerProperties.getProperty("wmq.host"));
mqConnectionFactory.setPort(Integer.valueOf(producerProperties.getProperty("wmq.port")));
mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(producerProperties.getProperty("wmq.manager"));
mqConnectionFactory.setChannel("MyChannel");

/**
 * Producer Section
 */
// Getting producer connection from the MQ server and starting it
Connection producerConnection = mqConnectionFactory.createConnection();
System.out.println("Going to start the producer connection...");
producerConnection.start();

// JMS messages are sent and received using a Session.
Session producerSession = producerConnection.createSession(false,
        Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
// Destination represents here our queue(testQ) on the MQ server.
Destination producerDestination = producerSession.createQueue(producerProperties.getProperty("wmq.queue.name"));

// MessageProducer is used for sending messages
MessageProducer producer = producerSession.createProducer(producerDestination1);
//create text message going to send

TextMessage sendingMessage = producerSession.createTextMessage("Hi Welcome");
sendingMessage.setJMSType(queueName);
System.out.println("Sending the message...");



//sending the message
producer.send(sendingMessage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the sample program.  If you installed to the default location on Windows, it's at:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\jms\samples\simple\SimpleMQMDWrite.java"
```

Or on *NIX platforms at:

```
/opt/mqm/samp/jms/samples/simple/SimpleMQMDWrite.java
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to the WMQ Information Center and look up JMSX* and JMS_IBM_* selectors.